# Custom linkhandler does not show up in PageLinkChooser

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am following the [Wagtail docs](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/rich_text_internals.html#rewrite-handlers) to create a custom link handler:

myapp.handlers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from wagtail.core.rich_text import LinkHandler

class UserLinkHandler(LinkHandler):
    identifier = 'user'

    @staticmethod
    def get_model():
        return get_user_model()

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls, attrs):
        model = cls.get_model()
        return model.objects.get(username=attrs['username'])

    @classmethod
    def expand_db_attributes(cls, attrs):
        user = cls.get_instance(attrs)
        return '<a href="mailto:%s">' % user.email
```

my_app/wagtail_hooks.py

```
from wagtail.core import hooks
from my_app.handlers import MyCustomLinkHandler

@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')
def register_link_handler(features):
    features.register_link_type(LinkHandler)
```

However, the handler does not show up in the admin widget. The expected behaviour is it should be in an option in the link type bar:

[image]

I've followed the docs exactly, is there something missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not part of `register_link_type`'s functionality. A link type handler only defines the mapping between the database representation of a link and the final HTML output - it doesn't provide any user interface support for actually inserting those links. As the linked documentation notes:

> This example assumes that equivalent front-end functionality has been added to allow users to insert these kinds of links into their rich text editor.

For that, you'll need to consult https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/extending_draftail.html.

Comment: Thanks, there's nothing in the docs about how to add another link class to the UI of the existing `PageLinkChooser`. Is this possible or should I create a new entity?

Comment: I've started a bounty as I think guidance on what the steps involved might be would be a helpful answer to have.